# Algorithm for most commonly used items

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, recommendation-engine

I'm working on a site which allows contractors to upload blueprints and place various assemblies on it for estimating purposes.  I'd like to use an algorithm so that if they place an assembly on a blueprint, and click on the assembly, they can see other assemblies that are most commonly used with that one (e.g. if they place a breaker box it could show that 50' of electrical wire is commonly also used) based using data from all the blueprints currently saved in the system.

Based on the research I've done, it appears that affinity analysis would be the best way to determine which other assemblies are most commonly used with each assembly.  I was wondering if anyone can provide any feedback if this would be the best algorithm to use or if there is a better one.  All the blueprint/assembly data is stored in an MS SQL database and the backend of the website is written in C# with the data provided to the site via a REST service.

Any information or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Your situation is too generically described for a recommendation; on-line ML sources give you much guidance on choosing an approach.

Answer (score 0):

"counting"

The problem, as you described it, does not require any particular algorithm. It is a simple counting operation, and can be performed by any decent database using `COUNT()`, `GROUP_BY`, and `WHERE`.